# Debian/Ubuntu:redirect boot messages to file?

Tags: logs, startup

I know that something similar it's been asked before but I'd like to know if is possible, during the boot, to **redirect the output (messages) also to a file**.

I mean, I know that I can find that informations spread between `/var/log/messages` (or `/var/log/syslog` on some systems) and `dmesg`, but is there a way to "register" all boot messages exactly the way they are printed on screen?

Comment: if `dmesg` is not enough for you, you can always connect an RS-232 interface, define RS-232 as the output and capture the boot in another PC/server. Or if in a virtualization  environment, capture the (virtualized) RS-232 output to a file.